# Unable to make angular-formly work within a ng-template of an angular-ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-formly, angular-template

I am using angular-formly to build a form inside an angular-ui-bootstrap modal, the following code works when the form is placed outside the modal template but it doesn't when placed inside the ng-template, it just doesn't print the fields at all.

I believe this should work but I don't know how the life-cycle of angular-formly runs, so I am unable to identify how to make the fields show up inside my bootstrap modal template.

The issue is clearly related to the ng-template, it appears not to render the form even if the fields array is passed correctly.

```
var app = angular.module("demo", ['dndLists', 'ui.bootstrap', 'formly', 'formlyBootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, User) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.loadingData = User.getUserData().then(function(result) {
      vm.model = result[0];
      vm.fields = result[1];
      vm.originalFields = angular.copy(vm.fields);
      console.log(vm);
    });

});

app.controller("AdvancedDemoController", function($scope, $uibModal){

    $scope.modalOpen = function(event, index, item){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: 'md',
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
});
```

In my view:

```
<!-- Template for a modal -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div ng-if="vm.loadingData.$$state.status === 0" style="margin:20px 0;font-size:2em">
            <strong>Loading...</strong>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.loadingData.$$status.state !== 0">
            <form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" novalidate>
                <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" form="vm.form">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
                </formly-form>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're treating the `ModalInstanceCtrl` as if it's using `controllerAs` (because you're using `vm` in your template, but it's not. Make sure that you're using `controllerAs`

Comment: I am actually using `<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="AdvancedDemoController as vm">` doesn't that replace the `controllerAs`?

Comment: Ok solved it! You were totally right I added the `controllerAs` and it worked! Please answer the question and I will mark it as the solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `$uibModal.open` you need to specify `controllerAs: 'vm'` (that's what you're template assumes the controller is defined as).